# NX remove root project from lint targets

Tags: angular, typescript, nrwl-nx

I'm migrating [my Angular app](https://github.com/azerothcore/Keira3) to NX and just managed to create some libraries. Now I would like to run the `nx affected` command, for example `nx affected:lint` but it fails with this error:

> ```
> nx run Keira3:lint
> Oops! Something went wrong! :(
>
> ESLint: 8.57.0
>
> No files matching the pattern "./src" were found.
> Please check for typing mistakes in the pattern.
>
> Warning: command "eslint ./src" exited with non-zero status code
> ```

The problem is that the "Keira3" project is just the name of the root project in the `package.json`, it's not an app or a library, but for some reasons NX thinks it has to run lint on it.

If I run `nx show projects --with-target lint`

I get:

```
acore-world-model
keira-config
keira-e2e
keira
Keira3
```

which is correct except for the last `Keira3` element.

Where is this list generated from? Where can I remove/add elements to such a list?

Comment: I think nx uses a glob to search for `project.json` files, to generate that list.

Comment: You could try removing the `lint` section from the `project.json`.

Comment: there is no `project.json` for the root project, just for the apps and libs

Comment: Another thing that I read was to ignore files using the `.eslintrc.json`. That error isn't from nx based on a github post, it is coming from eslint.

Comment: the error yes, the fact that the root project is considered a lint target is about nx (`nx show projects --with-target lint`)